# Find two vectors $a$ and $b$ in $M$ which are not scalar multiples of the other and show that $M$ is spanned by $a$ and $b$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $M$ be the subspace 
>   $$M = \{ (x_1,x_2,x_3)\in \mathbb{R}^3 :\, x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3 = 0\}$$
>   Find two vectors $a$ and $b$ in $M$ neither of which is a scalar multiple of the other. Then show that $M$ is the linear span of $a$ and $b$.

Here is my plan from end to start.

3) Show that $M$ is a linear span of two vectors, $a$ and $b$. (*Does this mean that $M$ is a two-dimensional space because its spanned by two vectors?)*

2) To do that, I must find two vectors $a$ and $b$ in $M$ that **are not scalar multiples** of each other.

1) Starting with the definition of $M$, one vector is already provided, $a = \langle ~x_1, -x_2, 2x_3~\rangle$.

---

I am struggling on finding a second vector, $b$, that is not a scalar multiple of $a$. I considered the zero vector and 1d or 2d vectors, but found counter examples so this was the wrong approach.

Then I thought, how would I determine if $x_1 - x_2 + 2x_3$ spanned $M$ alone? Maybe by showing that $M$ can't be spanned by a single vector, then the second vector needed would be more apparent, but I don't know how I would make such a determination.

Comment: Is $M:=\{x=(x_1,x_2,x_3): x_1-x_2+2x_3=0\} \subset \Bbb R^3$ ?

Comment: did you intend to add an "$=0$" condition inside $M$?

Comment: yes, sorry I will add that now

Comment: You're wrong with your choice of $a$, let $a=(1,1,0)$ for a start,  Furthermore, do you what the kernel of a linear map is?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe that has not been introduced in the book so I don't think we are allowed to use that as part of the answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that if $\vec{x} \in M$ then its components satisfy $$x_1-x_2+2x_3 = 0 \iff x_1 = x_2-2x_3.$$ Now we have
$$
\vec{x}
 = \begin{pmatrix} x_1 \\ x_2 \\x_3 \end{pmatrix}
 = \begin{pmatrix} x_2-2x_3 \\ x_2 \\x_3 \end{pmatrix}
 = x_2 \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix}
 + x_3 \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Can you complete the problem now?

Comment: Thanks that help. Can I simply conclude from here that $M$ is spanned by the two vectors?

Comment: @EvanKim yes, you can

Answer (score 2):

Are you not clear on the definition of "span"?  gt6989b showed how any vector in this space can be written as a linear combination of those two vectors.  Yes, that is exactly what "span" means!

You also ask "(Does this mean that M is a two-dimensional space because its spanned by two vectors?)".  NO, just spanning is not sufficient.  For example, The space of vectors (x, 0, 0) can be "spanned" by {(1, 0, 0), (2, 0, 0), (3, 0, 0)}.

In order to conclude that M is two dimensional, you would need to determine that there is a **basis** consisting of two vectors.  To be a "basis" the vectors must span the space **and** be independent.  In this problem, it is fairly easy to show that two vectors such that one is NOT a multiple of the other ARE independent.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. A lot of ideas seem to be getting mixed around in my head and remembered poorly.